# ERRO: Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tentando configurar o ambiente para começar a programar usando o flutter, na hora de executar o Android Virtual Devices, ele reporta esse  erro sobre o HAXM, já tentei desinstalar e instalar de novo, o Hyper-v está desativado mas sem sucesso ate o momento. o segundo erro tambem reportado pelo Android Studio,  ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Comment: Qual o processador que você usa? e em qual SO tá instalado o Android Studio?

Comment: WIN10 PRO 1703 - I3 7100T 3.4GHz

Comment: Já ativou o HAXM na bios?? A maioria, ou todas as placas (não sei ao certo) vem desabilitado o hardware acceleration.

Comment: Cara as opções de virtualização da intel no bios já estão ativas, ativei o turboBoost agora, mas sem sucesso ainda.